# Can't call a fact in the RHS of defrule in Jess

Tags: java, clips, jess

i have written this code in **jess** but i keep gettin this error and i don't understand why?

```
(deffacts prices (price apple 125) (price chips 45) (price cola 110) (price egg 700))
(defrule createBill (buy ?n $?) => (assert (bill ?n 0)))
(deffunction getTotalPrice (?list)
    (bind ?result 0) (foreach ?product $?products 
        (price ?product ?price)
        (bind ?result (+ ?result ?price)))
    (return ?result))
(defrule calculate ?i<-(bill ?n $?) (buy ?n $?products)  =>  (retract ?i) (bind ?result (getTotalPrice $?products))(assert (bill ?n ?result)))
(reset)
(assert (buy yaser cola egg))
(run)
```

and i get this error ???

```
Jess reported an error in routine Funcall.execute
        while executing (price ?product ?price)
        while executing (foreach ?product $?products (price ?product ?price) (bind ?result (+ ?result ?price)))
        while executing defrule MAIN::calculate
        while executing (run).
  Message: Undefined function price.
  Program text: ( run )  at line 41.
```

The problem is **Jess** is looking for a function named price but i want to use the fact `(price ... ...)`
any help is good :) **Yaser**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the error message is pretty clear, I think; there's no function named `price`, but the expression `(price ?product ?price)` is interpreted as a call to a function by that name.

I understand what you want `getTotalPrice` to do, but I can't understand your implementation; I think you're mistaken about what the [`apply`](http://www.jessrules.com/jess/docs/71/functions.html#apply) function does -- maybe you're confusing it with a similarly named function in some other language.

Anyway, the way to write `getTotalPrice` in Jess would be by using a query; see [here](http://www.jessrules.com/jess/docs/71/queries.html) to learn about those.

Comment: Thank you, but i tried to use apply function and remove it and got the same result, the problem is that i want Jess to look for the fact (price) that i defined not a function named price, PS. i edited the question

Comment: It's not `apply` -- it's the whole approach of trying to use `foreach` to drive pattern matching. That's just not how Jess works. As I said, you should use queries to select groups of facts to operate on. Follow the link in my answer and read that chapter of the manual.